# Transition between divs with update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

Here's the scenario: I have multiple div controls on an aspx page. I am using update panels to avoid page refresh. div contains controls like button, textbox:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">   
      <ContentTemplate>             
        <div id="divEnvironment" runat="server" visible="true">  
           <asp:Button ID="btnCred" runat="server" OnClick="btnCred_Click" Text="Proceed" Width="100px" />
       </div>
    </ContentTemplate> 
       <Triggers>          
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCred" EventName="Click" />               
       </Triggers> 
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">   
    <ContentTemplate>               
       <div id="divConfig" runat="server" visible="false"> 
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtDoamin" runat="server" Width="430px"></asp:TextBox>
       </div>
   </ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On button click, I have to submit data (server postback) as well as switch the visibility of div tags to display the next div:

```
protected void btnCred_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    SubmitData();   

    divEnvironment.Visible = false;              
    divConfig.Visible = true;           
}
```

Its working fine but what I am trying to achieve is that the transition between divs should be smooth (with delayed transition effects). I tried this:

```
 div {
        transition: visible 2s;
    }
```

But it didn't work. Actually the problem is update panel. It works without them but with update panel, css effects doesn't seems to work. 
Please suggest the best way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: what about visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;

Comment: actually the problem is update panel. It works without them but with update panel, css effects doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

"visible" could not be used, you should use visibility and opacity to make animation

make your buttons are html

use post method to submit

make css like this:

```
.active {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity:1;
}

#divEnvironment {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity:0;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s;
}

#divConfig {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity:0;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s;
}

and then if you add "active" class to each one with jquery you can see fade effect
but if you want to use slide animations you can use for example :
transform: translateY(-20%);

add active class with jquery for example:
$(btn).click(function(){ $("#divConfig").removeClass("active"); $("#divEnvironment").addClass("active") });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The div transition is working perfectly. But my POST method is failing to call the code-behind function.

Comment: Also, how can we call the page's controls like textbox, Label etc within the WebMethod in code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

@Houtan - This is the POST method I'm using:

```
 function btnCred_Click() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Transition.aspx/btnCred_Click",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

It returns the Error.

Answer (score 0):

you should post like this:

```
var Result = 0;
$.ajax(
{ url: "pathToPage/Transition.aspx/methodName",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: "{'id':'" + $("#txtId").val() + "','name':'" + $("#txtName").val() + "'}",
    success: function (data) {
        Result = data.d;
    },
    error: function () { Result = "error posting data to server"; }
});
return Result;
```